# Search directory in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Is there any way to set search directory for a module in node.js?

If a node package have modules like below structure

```
---node-modules 
    ---package
       ---lib
          module1.js
          module2.js
       index.js
```

How to import a specific module like `require('package/module1')` instead of `require('package/lib/module1')`, it looks hard in the code.

If is there any option to set search directory, then it can be search the module from the corresponding directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `package.json` of the package you want to require.

The file that is loaded when you `require` the module, is defined by the `main` property. You could edit it, but i strongly advise against it.

Instead, you could fork the package repository and change the `main` property of `package.json` to point to file you wish to require.

Then, in **your project** `package.json`, find the entry for the package, and insert your github/bitbucket/whatever repository url like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "package_name": "git+https://github.com/your_username/forked_repository.git"        
}
```